# How to color the 2 expressions of a legend in different colors?

Tags: r, plot

Some data:

```
dummy.dt <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1000))

plot(dummy.dt, type="n", xlab="x" , ylab="y", xaxt = "n", log = "y")

ABC = 1
XYZ = 2

rp = vector('expression',2)
rp[1] = substitute(expression(italic(A) == MYVALUE), 
                   list(MYVALUE = format(ABC, digits = 3)))[2]
rp[2] = substitute(expression(italic(X) == MYOTHERVALUE), 
                   list(MYOTHERVALUE = format(XYZ, digits = 3)))[2]

legend('top', legend = rp ,bty = 'n')
```

the last section is taken from [here](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2012/10/adding-p-values-and-r-squared-values-to-a-plot-using-expression/)
Result:

[image]

How to color the 2 expressions of the legend in different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the help page: `?legend`. It shows a `text.col` parameter. I tried offering a vector of valid color names and ... success:

```
 legend('top', legend = rp ,bty = 'n', text.col=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it was easy but if you need any excuse let me quickly say the help page wasn't entirely clear about how a vector would be used. This did seem to be how I would have designed it, but sometimes expectations are not met.